# Python list of dictionaries search with multiple input

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, search

Sorry for such a stupid question but im on deadend right now (1st time using python), how do i search Python list of dictionaries with multiple 
attribute ?

My current code is only can search by 1 attribute.

```py
people = [{'name': 'Alex', 'age': '19',
'grade': 80},
{'name': 'Brian', 'age': '17', 'grade':
90},
{'name': 'Junior', 'age': '17', 'grade':
90},
{'name': 'Zoey', 'age': '19', 'grade':
95},
{'name': 'joe', 'age': '18', 'grade':
90}]

entry=input("Check the name you want to search the grade :")

list(filter(lambda person: person['name'] == entry, people))
```

I want it to search by multitple attribute, so if i input either '17' or 90, the expected output is

```py
[{'name': 'Brian', 'age': '17', 'grade': 90},
 {'name': 'Junior', 'age': '17', 'grade': 90}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use two conditions connected by an `or` (while taking measures not to compare strings with numbers):

```
list(filter(lambda person: str(person['grade']) == entry or str(person['grade']) == entry, people))
```

At some point, a comprehension will be more readable:

```
[p for p in people if str(person['grade']) == entry or str(p['grade']) == entry]
```

And if you want to add more search keys, you can further DRY this out, using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
keys = ('name', 'grade', 'age')
filtered = [p for p in people if any(str(p[k]) == entry for k in keys)]
```